# Windows 10 blocking DNS queries on one interface when other interface returns Server Fault, in case of multiple active interfaces

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, windows-10

I have two active interfaces on my Windows 10 machine - Wi-Fi and Ethernet, each having their own set of DNS servers.

In ideal case I could see DNS request being sent on both the interfaces and response is also received from both the interfaces. But occasionally, the DNS on the Ethernet returns Server Fault in the response. In this case there is no DNS packet sent on the Wi-Fi. Is this the expected behavior? It happens only when DNS response has Server Fault in it.

Changing the DNS servers of the interface will work. But here I am really trying to understand the Windows DNS Client behavior.

Additional Info: Interface metric of the Ethernet is less than Wi-Fi i.e. Ethernet is the primary interface.

I have referred to the official Microsoft docs and found a feature called DNS Client service binding which may be related to my problem. But its description is vague and incomplete. I am not sure what is happening here. Also does Windows publish the DNS client design?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsclient/set-dnsclientserveraddress?view=windowsserver2019-ps might help you maybe

Comment: @djdomi   I do not want to change the DNS servers associated with the interface. I am just trying to understand the Windows DNS Client behavior. Edited the description to make it clear.

Comment: the isuse is, that windows always prefers first the WiFi adapter and after wards the cable one. Thats a known behavior.  and pelase update your question then its really unclear... https://faq-database.de/doku.php?id=en:x-and-y-problem